# Alternatives to a Replacement Key for Dell PowerEdge 2950 Server

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, physical-security

So ... Dell says they don't sell the part. I've read elsewhere that [they can be obtained through a VAR](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/946/p/19283819/19516621.aspx#19516621). Then there's the [bust open the lock option](http://www.fixya.com/support/t2320010-open_front_panel_dell_poweredge_1600sc).

Is there an easier, less aesthetically damaging alternative out there?

Comment: How about a Locksmith?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$5 - grab it now...

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-1K861-Front-Bezel-Cover-Keys-for-Dell-PowerEdge-Servers-Key-Number-361-/150978007847?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2326fd9327

Then go to get the thing duplicated a few times and you should be all set.

(this question will most likely be closed though)

Comment: Ah! If this question shouldn't be here, then I'd rather toss it. (I appreciate the eBay link all the same.)

Comment: You can accept the answer, it doesn't appear anyone is going to recommend it be closed for now.